# Probability that median falls between largest and smallest sample drawn

Tags: probability

I have no starting point on which formula to use:

One draws 5 samples from a cont. distribution. Now, what is the approx. probability p that the median of the Population falls within the smallest and largest samples drawn?** 
Can anybody guide me on which formula to use or if any other approach is better suited?